# character of tensor product of irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Question about Serre's book "Linear representations of finite groups" page 16. Suppose $V$ with character $\chi$ has a decompostion $m_1 W_1\oplus\dots\oplus m_hW_h$ where $m_i$ are non-negative integers and $W_i$ are irreducible with character $\chi_i$, so $\chi=m_1\chi_1+\dots+m_h\chi_h$. Form $W_i\otimes W_j$ with character $\chi _i\chi_j$. Serre claims that $\chi_i\chi_j$ is a linear combination of the $\chi_i$ with non-negative integer coefficients. Why?

Comment: Because **every** character is of the form $\sum_i m_i\chi_i$, when $\chi_i$ ranges over the irreducible characters.

Comment: Are you taking the $W_i$ to be *all* of the irreducible representations of $G$ (as opposed to just the ones that appear in $V$)?  If so, see Jyrki's comment.  If not, it's false without some additional hypotheses.

Comment: @RaviFernando is the fact the vectors spaces in the tensor product are irreducible subspaces of V is not sufficient to make it true in general?

Comment: @alexanderyaacov There are examples of finite groups $G$ and irreducible characters $\chi_1, \chi_2$ such that $\chi_1 \chi_2$ is itself an irreducible character different from $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$.  (Example:  take $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ to be the two nontrivial characters of $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.)  Then if $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$ is the corresponding representation, $\chi_1 \chi_2$ is not a linear combination of characters that actually occur in $V$.  But if you allow writing $V = W_0^{\oplus 0} \oplus W_1^{\oplus 1} \oplus W_2^{\oplus 1}$ and $\chi_1 \chi_2 = \chi_0$ then it's fine.